# What is the metric formula for this function?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following function:$$x^M=(v_1^R\tau^R+v_1^B\tau^B-\frac{a_1}{2}\tau^R\tau^B)\space cos\theta^M$$

Where red and blue are dimensions with units of $\tau$. The size of a third dimension, magenta, $x^M$, is a function of the coordinates, $\tau^R$ and $\tau^B$, and the angle between the $\tau$ coordinate axes, $cos\theta^M$. $v_1^R$, $v_1^B$, and $a_1$ are constants.

Also, $\theta^M$ being the angle between the axes, we have $cos\theta^M=\frac{d\tau^R}{d\tau^B}$.

The functions for $x\left(\tau^R,\tau^B,\theta^M=0\right)$ and $x\left(\tau^R,\tau^B,\theta^M=\pi / 2\right)$ looks like this:

[image]
I would like to know what the distance is between two sets of coordinates. I got as far as the partial derivatives:$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau^R}=(v_1^R-\frac{a_1}{2}\tau^R)cos\theta^M$$$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau^B}=(v_1^B-\frac{a_1}{2}\tau^B)cos\theta^M$$But then I got stuck because I don't know how to take a partial derivative of a derivative, in that $cos\theta^M$ should be equal to $\frac{d\tau^R}{d\tau^B}$ since the axes are allowed to rotate and $cos\theta^M$ tells us how $\tau^R$ changes with respect to $\tau^B$.
Is there a metric formula that will tell me what the distance is between $p_0=(\tau_0^R,\tau_0^B,\theta_0^M)$ and $p_1=(\tau_1^R,\tau_1^B,\theta_1^M)$?

Comment: This is difficult to decipher. You have a three-dimensional hypersurface in four-dimensional space? Where is there a metric? Is there some metric you haven't told us on the four-dimensional space? Even knowing a Riemannian metric, finding the geodesic distance is usually very difficult.

Comment: @TedShifrin - "You have a three-dimensional hypersurface in four-dimensional space" There is no assumption here about a fourth dimension. Why do you feel one is implied or necessary? "Where is there a metric" That's what I'm asking: what is the metric formula? Mathematica was able to draw it keeping $\theta$ constant, so it must exist.

Comment: I told you that your post is very difficult to understand. What is $x^M$? Drawing a surface doesn't mean that one can explicitly find the geodesic distance between two points on it. Tell me exactly how your *function* $x^M$ defines a manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin - I appreciate that it's difficult and I appreciate your patience. I'm still exploring the properties myself. $x^M$ is the extent (size) of the dependent dimension. The total size (extent) of the magenta dimension is a function of the red and blue coordinates and the angle between the red and blue coordinate axes. Magenta is the one-dimensional surface of a three dimensional manifold of {R,B,M).

Comment: So are we not looking at $x=x^M=f(\tau^R,\tau^B,\theta^M)$? That sounds like the graph of a function of $3$-variables, which lives in 4 dimensions.

Comment: @TedShifrin - I believe you are correct. The function is more like
$$x^M=f(\tau^R,\tau^B,\frac{dτ^R}{dτ^B})$$
So, yes, three coordinates, but the third parameter (dimension) is a derivative of the first two parameters, so the parameters to this function are not entirely independent. Having thought about this for the last hour, I don't know enough to say whether θ is truly an independent dimension or not, but it is definitely a parameter to the function that determines the size of the magenta dimension.

Comment: Your derivative expression doesn't really make sense. These coordinates give distances along the (moving) axes and the derivative doesn't make sense. Here's a radical suggestion: Fix two axes (say the usual $x,y$-axes) and give $(\tau^R,\tau^B)$ in terms of them and $\theta$: say $x=\tau^R+\tau^B\cos\theta$ and $y=\tau^B\sin\theta$. As $\theta$ is allowed to vary, you build a $3$-dimensional object, not a surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin - *"Your derivative expression doesn't really make sense"* What part doesn't make sense? The extent of magenta space, $x^M$, is a function of the angle between the red and blue temporal coordinate axes, $\theta$. Is there some rule of geometry that prevents this? Mathematica didn't have any trouble drawing it and I can easily imagine a geodesic from a point on the left figure to a point on the right figure as $\theta$ changes. I just don't have the skills to work out the metric formula. Putting that aside, your suggesting is interesting, I'll see how far I can take it.